# I'm trying fetch data from an api but it seems to be not working

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "hi This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String URL = "i have given a valid API, since its company's api i cant share";

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.e("response", response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("error", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }
}
```

Im trying fetch data from an api but it seems to be not working.
Neither of the toast are getting executed (response, error). 
I have included all dependencies and included internet permission too.
please help

Comment: "it seems to be not working". This is terribly vague. "response, error", this too could be a lot more specific. could you please update your question to contain all relevant information?

Comment: did you get anything in logcat?

Comment: It takes time to getting response from api. Please check your logcat.

Comment: Refer here [My GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ArbazGitHub/Volley-Api.git) for Volley.

Comment: logcat has nothing to show

Comment: do you have pass any parameters in your api

Answer (score 0):

Change Request.Method.GET to Request.Method.POST and try may be it solved...

If that not work then try this...
Use StringRequest instead JsonObjectRequest

Using StringRequest you need this change

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest (
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("response", response.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("error", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```